# What are/is the alternative(s) to changing the ad unit id constant all the time?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have an iOS app that contains ads from AdMob. Since Google's Get Started guide told me not to use my own id on a simulator, I have to change between my real id and the test id all the time.

When I am testing whether the ads will show up correctly, I use the test ids. After that, I need to archive the app for updating the app in iTunes Connect. This time, I need to change it to my real ids. Then, I found there are some really severe bugs so I need to change it back to the test ids to do debugging. After I killed the bugs, I need to change it back to real ids for another update...

As you can see, that is so annoying! I want to find a way to just "flip a switch" to change the ad ids. You know, when I want to change it to test ids or real ids, I can just delete a few human-readable characters (not those ad ids in some alien language) or something like that.

I know I can use constants for each of the ids:

```
let testId = "xxx"
let realId = "yyy"
let adId = testId
// And I'll use adId for all the places where required.
```

When I want to change it to my real id, I can just

```
let adId = realId
```

However, I need to change a lot of stuff if I got multiple ad ids in my app. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer by myself.

I found a property in `GADRequest` called `testDevices`. From the description of the property:

> Test Ads will be returned for devices with device IDs specified in this array

So if I put a test device's ID in that array, I don't need to change the IDs every time. And I found a constant called `kGADSimulatorID`. The description of it says

> Add this constant to the testDevices property's array to receive test ads on the simulator.

So I did this:

```
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
myAd.loadRequest(request)
```